# QA friendly stubbing and service virtualization tools?

Tags: tools

Wikipedia lists [several tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_virtualization) used to virtualize services (create stubs).
Some of them are purely focused on developers, some of them have GUIs and are more QA/tester friendly.

The ones that look QA friendly are:

- IBM Rational Test Virtualization Server
- CA Service Virtualization (formerly CA LISA)
- Parasoft Virtualize
- HP Service Virtualization
- SoapUI

Is there any other tools that can be easily used by QAs that had no exposure to programming nor command line tools? Preferably tools with GUIs?

Comment: Are you particularly asking for REST or other type of API testing tool?

Comment: @saifur mainly HTTP

Comment: Can't speak for the other tools, but I have used Parsoft tools in my previous job, and I would NOT recommend it. The virtualized component in particular was not intuitive to use.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 easy-to-use stub tools:

- **[Mockey](https://github.com/clafonta/Mockey/wiki)**
- **[Mocky](http://www.mocky.io/)** (for single responses only)

They both have GUI. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on [Stubmatic](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Stubmatic). It let's you stub HTTP(s) services like SOAP or REST web services or any HTTP(s) call.

> Why it is QA friendly? Because I created it for QAs only.

Starting with Stubmatic is just 3 steps task. Later on, you will have to map each request with response. Let me give you an example;

```
-  request:
      url: /stubs/(admin|staff|customer|security)

   response:
      body: response line
```

For complex use you may require the knowledge of regular expressions.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of [Stubmatic](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Stubmatic) .

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of tools with GUIs mentioned in [this comparison](http://trafficparrot.com/Service_virtualization_and_stubbing_tools_comparison.html):

- [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) for HTTP
- [Traffic Parrot](https://trafficparrot.com/features.html) for HTTP, GRPC, JMS, Files, IBM MQ plus more in [beta](https://trafficparrot.com/beta.html)
- [Hoverfly](https://hoverfly.io/) for HTTP

There are also a few more mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools):

- [API Simulator](https://apisimulator.io/) for HTTP
- [sMockin](http://www.smockin.com/#quick) for HTTP, WebSockets, Server Side Events, JMS, FTP
- [Wilma](https://epam.github.io/Wilma/) for HTTP

Answer (score -2):

CA Lisa & SOAP UI

Both don't need any programming skills.

Try with SOAP UI free version first, they have something like a mock service. Using it is pretty straight.